# Haskell Create and return variable

Tags: haskell, declaration

I'm new with Haskell and I have a little problem with creation and return variable.

Actually my problem is to create a variable in a function scope and to return it. For now i declare an empty variable in the function declaration and the function will return it.

For example I want to return the square root i of nb. Because I don't know how to create a variable i in the scope, I call mySqr with the good nb and the future square root i empty.

```
mySqr :: Int -> Int -> Int
mySqr nb i
    | i * i == nb = i
    | otherwise = mySqr nb (i + 1)
```

call: **mySqr 25 0**

It works but I would like it to be better.

Thanks you for your help.

Comment: Moderators, can we move this to code review?

Comment: @MichaelLitchard To interact with a moderator you should use the flag button in the bottom left of the post and enter an "other" flag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One typically makes a locally scoped function, often this function is given the name `go`:

```
mySqr :: Int -> Maybe Int
mySqr n = go 0
    where go i | i2 > n = Nothing
               | i2 == n = Just i
               | otherwise = go (i+1)
               where i2 = i*i
```

Here we return a `Maybe Int` that is `Nothing` if no square root exists. We know that the square root does not exists, if *i<sup>2</sup>>n*, since we only increase *i*. If we find the square root, we return it here wrapped in a `Just` data constructor. For example:

```
Prelude> mySqr 0
Just 0
Prelude> mySqr 1
Just 1
Prelude> mySqr 2
Nothing
Prelude> mySqr 3
Nothing
Prelude> mySqr 4
Just 2
```

Of course there are faster ways to calculate the square root. I leave that as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks you for your help !